# Entity Framework: уведомление сущностей об удалении другой сущности, на которую есть ссылка

Tags: entity-framework

Доброго времени суток.
Кто подскажет, как реализовать на базе Entity Framework такую штуку. Есть сущность клиент и есть сущность заказ. Сущность заказ ссылается на клиента и хранит в себе только его ID. Как при удалении клиента автоматически уведомить заказ (и все остальные сущности, которые держат ссылку на клиента) о том, что мы его собираемся удалить? А они уже решат (как вариант, бросят исключение или вернут false), позволить или нет.
Понятно, что начинать стоит с подписки на событие контекста SavingChanges, и выборки удаляемых объектов, а как дальше?
В идеале должно получится так, что при удалении любой сущности будут разосланы уведомления всем, у кого была на нее ссылка и кто реализует заданный интерфейс поддержки этих уведомлений.